# Efficiency of images vs XML drawable

Tags: android, xml, image, android-drawable

In Android which would be more preferable for an application's backgrounds / wallpapers: images created with your favorite vector-art application or defining the backgrounds in XML.
The majority of these backgrounds will be gradient-based (also keeping in-mind that Android often recalculates the gradient and you get the effect that the gradient is moving). I read this and didn't get what i wanted

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Aiden